# Использование элементов класса в другой форме

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2012

Доброго времени суток!
Совсем недавно перешёл от консольного программирования на формы, а точнее пытаюсь написать приложение на Windows Phone 8. Разная ерунда получается без труда, а вот если что посложнее... В Общем, вот в чём вопрос:

Имеется форма Page1.xaml.cs, на которой расположены элементы: 4 TextBox'а и Button1.
Я решил добавить в проект новый класс Car.cs со следующим содержанием:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public class Car
    {
        public string marka;
        public string model;
        public int maxspeed;
        public int horsepower;
    }
}
```

В Page1.xaml.cs я создаю экземпляр класса:

```
Car auto = new Car();
```

И начинаю присваивать через обычную точку "." полям класса данные из TextBox'ов. Тут проблем никаких.

Далее я создаю новую форму/класс Page2.xaml.cs, где у меня расположены 4 элемента типа TextBlock и кнопка Button2. Итак, вопрос: как мне получить доступ к переменной auto, а вернее к её полям в новой форме? (я хочу заполнить TextBlock'и данными из auto при нажатии на Button2).

**Содержимое Page1:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Car auto = new Car();
            auto.marka = TextBox_marka.Text;
            auto.model = TextBox_model.Text;
            auto.maxspeed = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_maxspeed.Text);
            auto.horsepower = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox_horsepower.Text);

            MessageBox.Show("Информация добавлена успешна!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Содержимое Page2:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace PhoneApp1
{
    public partial class Page2 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public ShowRandomCar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            *Код кнопки*
        }

    }
}
```

Сразу хочу сказать, что я только учусь, так что прошу не кричать на меня по поводу криво-реализованной инкапсуляции и т.д. Я просто хочу понять, как правильно наладить связь между формами.

Comment: Самое простое - сделайте в page2 паблик свойство типа Car и передавайте auto туда после открытия страницы.
static класс, в конце концов, можно использовать

Comment: Обычно разделяют гуй и логику, т.е. по нажатию кнопки Вы меняете где-то контекст.
Выделите отдельно класс (можно даже сингелтоном) контекста и общайтесь с ним из откуда угодно.

Comment: +почитайте про IoC контейнеры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте не так.

Во-первых, WPF — не Winforms. Поэтому вам надо сделать из `Car` `ViewModel` и забыть о ретроградском перебрасывании данных вручную, а воспользоваться `Binding`'ом.

Итак, класс `Car`:

```
public class Car : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ManufacturerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Manufacturer", typeof(string), typeof(Car));

    public string Manufacturer
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ManufacturerProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ManufacturerProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Model", typeof(string), typeof(Car));

    public string Model
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(Property, value); }
    }

    // ну и т. д.

    public Model.Car Create()
    {
        return new Model.Car(Manufacturer, Model, ...);
    }

    static Car FromModel(Car.Model car)
    {
        return new Car()
        {
            Manufacturer = car.Manufacturer,
            ...
        };
    }
}
```

Теперь ваши свойства могут участвовать в `Binding`'е, и пора этим воспользоваться.

```
<PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="PhoneApp1.Page1" ... >
    ...
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Manufacturer}"/>
    ...
    <Button Command="New">Add new car</Button>
    ...
</PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Не забываем указать нужный DataContext при запуске `Page1`:

```
car = new Car();
new Page1() { DataContext = car }.Show();
```

У вас появилась команда, которую надо обработать. Регистрируем обработчик в начале исполнения программы:

```
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
        typeof(PhoneApplicationPage),
        new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New, AddCar, CanAddCar));

void AddCar(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    model.Cars.Add(car.Create());
}
```

Ну и теперь понятно, как отобразить другое окно, соответствующее данной модельной машине:

```
new Page2() { DataContext = Car.FromModel(modelCar) }.Show();
```

---

Почитайте про MVVM, без него никуда.

Comment: Только не понятно к чему вы про wpf?

Comment: Ой, да, именем файла `Page1.xaml.cs` навеяло. А под WP8 не то же самое?